# массивы с текстом js

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
 function karl(pos){
     ris=["a","b","c"]}
```

Нужно по аргументу функции найти определенный элемент в массиве

В html у меня в теге  есть собылие onclick="karl(0)"
в другом  onclick="karl(1)". Нужно чтобы по нажатию на картинку открывался браузер в новом окне и там была эта картинка. Но вся проблема в том, что я не могу додуматься как достать элемент массива по его id т.к. он должен совпадать с аргументом функции

Comment: `ris[pos]`?....

Comment: А зачем еще раз делать обращение к данным, если у вас в картинке уже есть src данной картинки сделайте `<a href="patch/img"><img scr="patch/img"></a>` или передайте src в onclick `<img scr="patch/img" onclick="kart(patch/img)">`

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
const ris = [
  "https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_header.v107.lg.svg"
];

const openImage = key => window.open(ris[key]);
```

HTML

```
<img src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_header.v107.lg.svg" onclick="openImage(0)" />
```